# Pandas: conditional cumsum with bandwidth function

Tags: python, pandas

I want to have a conditional column created with the underlying logic: if signal is 1 I add 5 to the current value, if its negative I remove 5 and if its 0 I do nothing. With .cumsum() on pandas its clear for me how to do it, but problem is that I want to restrict this in case value hits a certain bandwidth (in this example 45-55). In the example below once value hits 55, another positive signal will not increase it, but wait until negative signal.

Does anyone know how I can add this theoretical bandwidth in my code?

Before:

| signal | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 0 | 50 |
| -1 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| 0 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 |
| -1 | 50 |

After:

| signal | value | value created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 55 |
| 0 | 50 | 50 |
| -1 | 50 | 45 |
| 1 | 50 | 55 |
| 0 | 50 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 | 55 |
| -1 | 50 | 45 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You description doesn't seem to match the provided output. From the description, here is what I understood:

```
df['value created'] = (df['value']
                       # add 5 to the current value,
                       # if its negative I remove 5 
                       # if its 0 I do nothing
                       .add(df['signal'].mul(5))
                       # restrict this in case value hits a certain bandwidth
                       # (in this example 45-55)
                       .clip(lower=45, upper=55)
                      )
```

output:

```
   signal  value  value created
0       1     50             55
1       0     50             50
2      -1     50             45
3       1     50             55
4       0     50             50
5       1     50             55
6      -1     50             45
```

Comment: @idiot_at_work it's not in the description but in the provided output, I'll correct it